# Facebook Suspicious Account Access from private IP space

Tags: facebook, security, facebook-account

I received a "Suspicious Account Access" notification from Facebook telling me that someone has logged into my account from a "computer, mobile device or other location you've never used before". When I logged into my account, Facebook showed me a page which claims my account was accessed from "10.158.15.35".

[image: Facebook Access from 10.158.15.35]

The 10.0.0.0/8 range is not publicly routed IP address space, it is reserved for local use, so this is not a case of someone trying to access my account over the public Internet.

Has anyone else seen anything similar? Does this mean that someone at Facebook is trying to break into my account, or is this some kind of bug in their system?

Answer (score -2):

The i.p address which you have been provided is **class A** i.p address i.e it is meant only  reserved for private use and can be used inside any organization(i.e it might be from any of the shared computers of the network).
Facebook wont try to break into your account, click on i didn't recongnize and navigate to next tabs, usually facebook would trace the ip location too ,if you suspect it's an issue then report [here](http://facebook.com/hacked)

Comment: Exactly - it is a private IP address from Facebook's perspective. Presumably Facebook's gateway routers block private addresses from outside of their network, which implies that someone found a way to try to log in to my account from a private address within Facebook's own network. I have already clicked 'I Don't Recognize' and changed my password, but it is odd to see a private IP address here.